# Check editText input validation

Tags: android, validation, url, android-edittext

I want to make sure editText input is an URL ends with .com, .net, not some other characters, numbers etc. I implemented below:

```
public class NewCard extends Activity {

EditText txtWebsite;
Button save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_card);

save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override   
public void onClick(View v) {

EditText txtWebsite = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWebsite);
String Website=txtWebsite.getEditableText().toString();

isValidUrl (Website);

}
});
}

public boolean isValidUrl (String txtWebsite){

Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$");
                Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(txtWebsite); 
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                     return true;
               }else {
               return false;
              }

         }
```

My layout:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtWebsite"
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Website"
    android:capitalize="none"
    android:textColorHint="#262d35"
     />
```

When i run the application, seems "Url validator" is not functioning. How can i validate the text?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you're actually asking... However to start your isValidUrl method is expecting a string to be passed but you are passing it an EditText. To get the string out of the EditText use txtWebsite.getText().toString()

Comment: simply, i want to check editText input is an URL or some other characters, numbers etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to check if the url is a "url". the method `matches()` to see if it is an url in this case.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(string);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
             //It's an url
       }else {
       //Not an url
       }
```

For example:

```
public boolean isValidUrl (String txtWebsite){
 Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(txtWebsite);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
             return true;
       }else {
       return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: thx @Luis Alberto but for character sequence: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ ) i am confused

Comment: no your answer is what i need. but over Patter regex characters i had this error:Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ ). If we can correct this thats fine.

Comment: And i think APK is updated and instead these characters we need to use such like \b \t etc. Im not sure.

Comment: Your edit is not the problem, the problem was that you need to double escape in java, otherwise Java does the escaping, not the regex engine. So you need to remove the square brackets again and replace all single \'s with double \\'s to escape them in for Java, that way they arrive as a single \ in the Regex engine.

Comment: Thx its corrected. But i still cant check the input. i upload my entire code. Could u pls check and advise me.

Comment: Also, be mindful of that your regular expression is by no means exhaustive, something like youtu.be/wxu7eZrPUyQ would not be recognized for example (neither would anything with a scheme or protocol in front)

Comment: I insert isValidUrl(Website); inside my save.onClickListener to call function. And function itself is at the bottom there. What else i can do im stacked.

Comment: @Umitk I'm confused, you mean that you can't call the method?

Comment: @BartEnkelaar He said that he wanted to check if the text written is an url, i understand your point i know it won't work for url like: "youtu.be/wxu939ew", but he didn't specified that he wanted one for short url. :-)

Comment: I think he's calling the method but it's probably not working because of the square brackets, right now it's probably only matching something like &.org$] -- As a test you can try to give it that input, if that matches, all you need to do is remove the outer square brackets.

Comment: Also, should that negation be there before the find?

Comment: @BartEnkelaar oooh sorry i found the error. I copied that code from an app i was working with, and i forgot to erase the ! :)

Comment: @BartEnkelaar Right now it matches everything, possibly something wrong in code

Comment: Yeah, remove the ! in front of matcher.find() like Luis did 10 minutes ago :-) Edit: Or use matches(), even better! :-)

Comment: Yeah :) @BartEnkelaar the matches() method would be better for this case.

Comment: Unfortunately no :/ I did as you said and i call the method as  isValidUrl (Website); from button.setOnClickListener to check during form saved. But i can still insert any character as before.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see whether something is a URL or not you can indeed use a Regular expression for that, however how stringent you make your check is all dependent on what you want.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator the full scheme for a URL is: `scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id`

To check this properly with a regular expression you could try this (presented as a JavaScript RegEx for readability):

```
/^(\w+://)?([\w\-]\.)+\w+(:\d+)?/?(\w+/)*\w*(\?([^=]+=[^&]+&?)+)?$/
```

This should match anything from goo.gl to https://maps.google.com/?ll=50.233234,10.865355&spn=0.001812,0.004128&t=h&z=19&layer=c&cbll=50.233234,10.865355&cbp=12,0,,0,0&photoid=po-92986447

The only problem is that it would also match R.E.M as a URL.

To mitigate this you could do stuff like specifically list top level domains as done in the earlier answer, but you should probably be [exhaustive](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db) in your list.

In truth it's a fairly complicated problem, so perhaps it helps to specify the boundary problems of your input? Are you only expecting youtube links? Are you only expecting typed in base links without query string? Please elaborate.

Comment: I want text to end by one of these: .com, .edu, .my and so on.

Comment: If that's truly the only thing you want to check all you need to do is use @Luis Alberto his code with this Java String as regular expression: "\\.(com|edu|my)$" That will check whether the string ends with those top level domains. Any other domain you want to check you can just add with a pipe like for example com|edu|my|nl to add the nl top level domain. You can also add them in all caps if you want to adjust for that.

Comment: Yes i did use his code. But the problem it doesnt work. I also upload my entire code above. Could you pls check?

Comment: Replace the line if (!matcher.find()) { by if (matcher.matches()) { , that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** 
* This is used to check the given URL is valid or not.
* @param url
* @return
*/

private boolean isValidUrl(String url) {
Pattern p = Patterns.WEB_URL;
Matcher m = p.matcher(url);
if(m.matches())
    return true;
else
return false;
}
```